# Errors in dice rolling game

Tags: javascript

I have to get the user to choose

- to use 2 to 7 dice to play with, and
- the number of rounds they want to play.

The dice are rolled and arranged in descending order to to make the possible biggest number.

After each round the values are added. The highest score after the selected number of rounds is the winner.

I can't get past the number of dice.

I can get the desired number of die to show, but can't get the round right.

Then the score board which holds the score all the players score against the computer arranged in descending order too till you exit the game. so it has leader board sort of thing. so it will have option of new game. username input,etc.

My code so far:

```
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function roll() {
      var result = 0;
      var charcode = 0;
      result = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
      charcode = String.fromCharCode(9856 + result);
      return charcode;
    }

    function play() {
      // create dice array
      var humanDice = new Array();
      var computerDice = new Array();

      // totals
      var humanTotal = 0;
      var computerTotal = 0;

      // score
      var score = "";

      // roll the dice 
      var i = "";
      var j;
      var z = prompt("Please enter number of turn you want", 2);
      var n = prompt("Please enter number of die you want to play with", 2);
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < z; j++) {
          humanDice[i] = roll();
          humanTotal += humanDice[i];
          computerDice[i] = roll();
          computerTotal += computerDice[i];
        }
      }

      // display human dice
      score = humanDice.sort(function (a, b) {
        return b - a;
      });

      document.getElementById('humanDice').innerHTML = score;

      // display computer dice
      score = computerDice.sort(function (a, b) {
        return b - a;
      });
      document.getElementById('computerDice').innerHTML = score;

      document.getElementById('humanTotal').innerHTML = humanTotal;
      document.getElementById('computerTotal').innerHTML = computerTotal;
    }

  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" onclick='play()'>
  <h3>Human</h3>
  <div id='humanDice' style="font-size: 64px; line-height: normal;"></div>
  <p id='humanTotal' class='total'></p>

  <div id='computer' class='playerArea'>
    <h3>Computer</h3>
    <div id='computerDice' style="font-size: 64px; line-height: normal;">
    </div>
    <p id='computerTotal' class='total'></p>
  </div>
  <div id='roll'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have edited your post and re-formatted your code for better readability. In so doing, I found MANY syntax errors in your HTML and JavaScript. You were missing closing `<div>` tags or had them in the wrong place, your closing `<head> ` tag was in the wrong place, you had stray semi-colons inside your HTML elements, your nested loop was incorrectly written and more.  Please compare your source code to this corrected version.

Comment: @ScottMarcus you shouldn't edit OP's code other than to help with format. If it's related to the problem, you should answer the question instead with the corrected code.

Comment: @EmileBergeron The syntax issues weren't related to the problem. This is all preliminary. That is why no answer was provided.

Comment: @ScottMarcus See [When should I make edits to code?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/1218980)

Comment: @EmileBergeron From that link: "DON'T: Fix Syntax (non-closed brackets, missing semi-colons, etc.), **unless they are obviously not relevant to the question**
Fix typos (misspelled function calls, variable names, etc.), **unless they are obviously not relevant to the question**"

Comment: @ScottMarcus but here, everything is related to the question since the whole code is a mess.

Comment: @EmileBergeron The HTML errors would have no impact on the JavaScript logic and the nested `for` loops were not going to cause the OPs issue either. I read the question and I know what I edited. None of it would be responsible for the problem(s).

Comment: Thanks Scott Marcus , i can see the changes I didn't put the curly brackets in the inner for loop ,but still i don't know why its  not getting the rounds going and another thing i would like to ask youz if i can return both charcode and result from the roll function as i would need it for the scoreboard it , i tried it before and could n't get both,

Comment: Hi guys can someone please guide whats happening wrong i have tried a few combination for the embedded loop but nothing seems to work, the total gives the number of round preceeded by a zero but all in the same line can't seem to put a <br> between them , sorry i am beginner and there might still  be many flaws in the code as Scott pointed out to me , but  a of guidance in the right direction can be helpful to me understand the subject, i can do it with switch case or  radio button sytle, as my number of dice is working  but i don't think i will learn this concept that i m trying to do, thanks

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible. Read through it and see if you can understand what you wrote. Edit it until it is a meaningful question that can be understood by a reader.

Answer (score 0):

You should really group these attributes (rolls,total,etc.) inside objects for cleanliness. Then you'd have playerH.total and playerC.rolls and so on.
**Your basic mistake was the index inside your dice arrays.**
The two loops over **i** and **j** should result in **rounds times diceset** entries, you kept overwriting the first i results!
https://jsfiddle.net/csqmxxey/1/

The important part:

```
for(let i = 0; i < dieset; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j < rounds; j++){
        var idx = j * dieset + i;
        humanDice[idx] = roll();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Mmmh. Something is still up .. I just rolled again [4:3] and the computer got a score of 1 even though he rolled: ⚄, ⚅, ⚀, ⚄, ⚅, ⚄, ⚀, ⚀, ⚂, ⚀, ⚁, ⚃

Comment: thanks for pointing in the right direction , since i posted the question i have done a bit on it an able to getting it going to some extent ,but surely yours will help me understand it better.thanks Flowron.

Comment: Flowtrom at the score you are calling array[0] instead of adding or the whole array thats is why it was score showed 1, thanks again

Comment: Hehehe. *sigh* didn't see the forest for the trees ;-)

Comment: eyes>0&&eyes<7) ? String.fromCharCode(9856 + (eyes-1)) : ""; },can you please explain me :"", bit and?bit please

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator Basically it's a shortend IF. If eyes is a legal value 1..6 we return the proper character, otherwise an empty string.